# Windows Command Prompt Not working From Python

Tags: python, mysql, windows, command-line

I am trying to get the following command (which works when entered manually to shut down mysql server) working from python.

The line of code I am running is:

```
os.system('"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqladmin" -u demo -pdemopw shutdown')
```

Any ideas why this would work from the command prompt, but not from os.system, and how I can fix it?

Comment: that was it.  thanks so much.  I was thinking about doing that, but then thought b/c it worked in the actual command prompt, that it wasn't being escaped.  Anyways, thanks so much, you just ended a 2 hour trek through the abyss for me.

Comment: Use raw strings. Stick a `r` in front of your command string, it will take `\b` and use it literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Windows file\folder paths, I almost always use raw strings. Here is an example:

```
sql_admin = r"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqladmin"
```

Notice the `r` at the beginning of the string. That turns the string into a raw string. If you do not do this, then Python will look at the backslashes for special characters, such as `\n` (new-line), `\t` (tab) or `\b` (backslash). You have the latter in your string.

One way to find out what's going on is to try printing the string in the interpreter. Take a look at the following example:

```
>>> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqladmin"
'C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\x08in\\mysqladmin'

>>> r"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqladmin"
'C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqladmin'
```

There are two alternatives to using raw strings. The first one is to just escape the backslashes:

```
>>> "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqladmin"
```

I've always found that a bit ugly and somewhat harder to read. You can also replace the backslashes with forward slashes:

```
>>> "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/bin/mysqladmin"
```

This will work, although it looks kind of odd if you're a Windows guy. So in the end, I still recommend using raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `\` to `/` and it should work.